# ContourPlot gives wrong output

Tags: plotting

I want to Plot a function

```
c1[t_, TT_, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2]=-((E^(-(1/TT) - 
      1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) (-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 (-1 + 
       5 E^(2/TT)) ((0. + 0. I) + 
       0.0064 E^(
        1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.008 E^(
        1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.008 E^(-(1/4)
           t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) - 
       0.008 E^(-(1/4)
           t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) + 
       0.0016 E^(
        1/4 t (-6 (1 + 2 Cosh[1/TT]) + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.0576 E^(
        1/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.176 E^(
        2/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.5824 E^(
        3/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.84 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.8576 E^(
        5/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       1.184 E^(
        6/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       1.3824 E^(
        7/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.2576 E^(
        1/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.016 E^(
        2/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       3.0624 E^(
        3/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       1.88 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       2.2224 E^(
        5/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       1.376 E^(
        6/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.5824 E^(
        7/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.2 E^(1/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.16 E^(2/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       2.48 E^(3/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       2.72 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       3.08 E^(5/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       2.56 E^(6/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.8 E^(7/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.2 E^(1/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.16 E^(2/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       2.48 E^(3/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       2.72 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       3.08 E^(5/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       2.56 E^(6/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.8 E^(7/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.2576 E^(
        1/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) + 
       0.016 E^(
        2/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) - 
       3.0624 E^(
        3/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) - 
       1.88 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       2.2224 E^(
        5/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) - 
       1.376 E^(
        6/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) + 
       0.5824 E^(
        7/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) + 
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) + 
       0.0576 E^(
        1/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.176 E^(
        2/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + 
       0.5824 E^(
        3/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.84 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.8576 E^(
        5/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       1.184 E^(
        6/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       1.3824 E^(
        7/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) - 
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) + (
       0.64 E^(2/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.12 E^(3/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.28 E^(4/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       2.48 E^(5/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.64 E^(6/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.28 E^(7/TT - 3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.64 E^(2/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.32 E^(3/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.28 E^(4/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.32 E^(5/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.64 E^(6/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.32 E^(7/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.32 E^(3/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.0064 E^(
        1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.008 E^(
        1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.008 E^(-(1/4)
           t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.008 E^(-(1/4)
           t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.0016 E^(
        1/4 t (-6 (1 + 2 Cosh[1/TT]) + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.016 E^(-(1/2) t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.016 E^(-(1/2) t (5 Coth[1/TT] + 3 Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.304 E^(
        2/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.72 E^(3/TT + 
         1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.48 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.92 E^(5/TT + 
         1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.696 E^(
        6/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.28 E^(7/TT + 
         1/4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT + 1/
          4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.704 E^(
        2/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.92 E^(3/TT + 
         1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       3.48 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       3.72 E^(5/TT + 
         1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       3.296 E^(
        6/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       2.08 E^(7/TT + 
         1/4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT + 1/
          4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.4 E^(2/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.2 E^(3/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       2 E^(4/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.8 E^(5/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.6 E^(6/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.8 E^(7/TT + 
         1/4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.4 E^(2/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.2 E^(3/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       2 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.8 E^(5/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.6 E^(6/TT - 
         1/
          4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.8 E^(7/TT - 
         1/4 t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.704 E^(
        2/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.92 E^(3/TT - 
         1/4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       3.48 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       3.72 E^(5/TT - 
         1/4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       3.296 E^(
        6/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       2.08 E^(7/TT - 
         1/4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT - 1/
          4 t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
           1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.304 E^(
        2/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       0.72 E^(3/TT - 
         1/4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.48 E^(4/TT - 
         1/4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.92 E^(5/TT - 
         1/4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.696 E^(
        6/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.28 E^(7/TT - 
         1/4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.512 E^(
        8/TT - 1/
          4 t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
            Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.4 E^(5/TT - 1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       0.6272 E^(6/TT - 1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - (
       1.6 E^(7/TT - 1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 + (
       1.024 E^(8/TT - 1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)])/(-1 + E^(1/TT))^2 - 
       0.08 E^(-(1/2) t Coth[1/(2 TT)]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.08 E^(-(1/2) t Coth[1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)]
         Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.08 E^(4/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.08 E^(6/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.02 E^(1/
         4 t (-6 - 12 Cosh[1/TT] + 
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.07 E^(1/
         4 t (-2 - 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.05 E^(1/
         4 t (2 - 4 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.05 E^(-(1/4)
           t (-2 + 4 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.07 E^(-(1/4)
           t (2 + 8 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.02 E^(-(1/4)
           t (6 + 12 Cosh[1/TT] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]]) Csch[
          1/TT]) Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.1 E^(-(1/2) t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.04 E^(-(1/2) t (5 Coth[1/TT] + 3 Csch[1/TT])) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.112 E^(1/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.04 E^(2/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.58 E^(3/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.64 E^(4/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.208 E^(5/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 + 
       0.64 E^(6/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.256 E^(7/TT - 1/2 t (3 + 5 Cosh[1/TT]) Csch[1/TT]) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2 - 
       0.02 Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)]
         Csch[1/(
         2 TT)]^2 (Cosh[3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]] - 
          Sinh[3/2 t Coth[1/(2 TT)]]) + (
       0.08 Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2)/(
       Cosh[1/2 t Coth[1/TT]] + Sinh[1/2 t Coth[1/TT]]) - (
       0.113137 E^(3/TT) Sqrt[17 + Cosh[2/TT]] Csch[1/(2 TT)]^2)/(
       Cosh[1/2 t Coth[1/TT]] + Sinh[1/2 t Coth[1/TT]]) - 
       0.08 Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)]
         Csch[1/(
         2 TT)]^2 (Cosh[4/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]] + 
          Sinh[4/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]]) + 
       0.08 Sqrt[1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)]
         Csch[1/(
         2 TT)]^2 (Cosh[6/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]] + 
          Sinh[6/TT - 1/2 t Coth[1/TT]]) + (
       1.6 E^(3/TT) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(
         4/TT)] (Cosh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])] - 
          Sinh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])]))/(-1 + E^(1/
         TT))^2 - (
       2.32 E^(4/TT) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(
         4/TT)] (Cosh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])] - 
          Sinh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])]))/(-1 + E^(1/
         TT))^2 + (
       0.2048 E^(6/TT) Sqrt[
        1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(
         4/TT)] (Cosh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])] - 
          Sinh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])]))/(-1 + E^(1/
         TT))^2 + (
       0.633568 E^(3/TT) Sqrt[
        17 + Cosh[2/TT]] (Cosh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])] - 
          Sinh[1/2 t (3 Coth[1/TT] + Csch[1/TT])]))/(-1 + E^(1/
         TT))^2))/((-1 + E^(2/TT))^2 Sqrt[
     1 + 34 E^(2/TT) + E^(4/TT)] (-1 + 4 E^(2/TT) + 5 E^(4/TT))))
```

, with the following code

```
ContourPlot[
 c1[t, TT, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2], {TT, 0.05, 10}, {t, 0.05, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap", WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

and the colour function

```
legend = BarLegend[{"LightTemperatureMap", {0, 0.601}}, 11, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> 550]
```

[image]

The ContourPlot gives the following output:

[image]

It looks, as if c1[t, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2] has (at least) two local maxima between t=0 and t=3 (at ca. 0.28 and 1.6). But if one plot c1[t, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2], one sees it is not the case

```
Plot[c1[t, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

For me ContourPlot and Plot give totally different output. Why it is so? Is the colour coding in ContourPlot different than in Legend?

I use Mathematica 10.4.0.0.

I have to add some text to post my question, but I don't think something else is relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is `ContourPlot` normalizes the color it passes to the color function to the range 0-1, so your `BarLegend` color scale is not corresponding to the data range.

If you want to use a `BarLegend` that corresponds exactly to the contour plot the best bet is to define your own color function and do your own range scaling:

```
cf[c_] := ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"][c/.6];
```

now plot and specify `ColorFunctionScaling->False` :

```
ContourPlot[
 c1[t, TT, 0, 0, 1, 0.4, 0.2], {TT, 0.05, 10}, {t, 0.05, 3}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

i used the embedded `PlotLegend` here as well so you can see it is the same.

[image]

now the bar legend..

```
legend = BarLegend[{cf[#] &, {0, .6}}, Range[0, .6, .1], 
  LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> 550]
```

[image]

note if we add the embedded legend to your original plot:

[image]

you see that light greenish color is the max by the auto normalization
(I honestly can not see why it picked that color from that scheme for the max..)

Comment: Great, many thanks!